# Rails.cache.read is not reading in test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

I want to test my caching functionality in Rails but Rails.cache.read(cache_key) is not working.

```
describe 'when crucible data is cached' do
  context 'when collect_review is called first time' do

    before(:all) do
      Rails.cache.clear
    end

    let(:attributes) { FactoryBot.attributes_for(:review) }

    it 'calls crucible api' do
      allow(CrucibleCollector).to receive(:collect_reviews)
        .with(author, last_monday.strftime('%b %-d, %Y'), last_sunday.strftime('%b %-d, %Y'))
        .and_return([attributes])

    expect(CrucibleCollector).to receive(:collect_reviews).exactly(1).times

    subject
  end

    it 'cache key should not exist' do
      expect(Rails.cache.exist?(cache_key)).to eq false
    end
  end

  context 'when collect_review is called for subsequent requests' do
    let(:attributes) { FactoryBot.attributes_for(:review) }

    it 'cache read should exist' do
      subject
      expect(Rails.cache.read(cache_key)).to eq(attributes)
    end

    it 'does not call crucible api' do
      subject
      expect(CrucibleCollector).not_to receive(:collect_reviews)
    end
  end
end
```

I want to test when the request is new then it should call API and get the data. When there is another request then it should get the data from the cache.